# Benefit of C++ to System Administrators

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu

What benefit could C++ bring to system administrators?

I am working on Windows and Ubuntu. If I learn C++, where could I implement it in system administration, Please specify some of its benefits.

Comment: Not the language I'd choose for such tasks. Python / ruby / bash is your friend as a sysadmin (speaking without professional experience)

Comment: Especially on Linux/Unix C++ isn't the first choice - most system libraries, kernel things, ... are C, not C++

Comment: Even so, most system administration tasks are best solved with scripting, so the shells and the tools that go with it, Perl and Python are much more useful first choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up, I don't see much benefit if you do ONLY administrative tasks.

The only case it would be of benefit is if these conditions are true:

- the tasks you want to automate requires maximum performance on each platforms (like processing very high quantity of data, but that's not an usual administrator task);
- you have enough experience, knowledge of modern C++ and confidence to not see the language itself as a barrier;
- you are allowed to spend more time coding than if it was python for example;
- you don't fear the C++ lack of text encoding help/utilities and the potential traps related to this;

Basically that means it's not really suited for this. I would use Python for cross-platform admin tasks. Maybe occasional c++ for very very demanding tasks or if you already wrote the task in Python and it blows the memory or take too much time - that can happen but it's rare.